# Write $F(x) = \cos^2(x+9)$ as function composition $F = f \circ g \circ h$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been given the task to write $F(x) = \cos^2(x+9)$ as function composition $F = f \circ g \circ h$. However, I don't know how to do this without knowing what the functions of $f$, $g$, and $h$ are. Since they're not defined for me, I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You work from the outside in. $f$ is the function applied last, and of the three operations present, the squaring happens last in numerical evaluation. So, let $f(x)=x^2.$ The second-to-last thing that happens is taking the cosine, so let $g(x)=\cos(x).$ The very first thing that happens is the shifting, so let $h(x)=x+9$. Then $F=f\circ g\circ h.$

Comment: Thanks! This helps!